# Change input name of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, activemodel

Using the `ActiveAttr`:

```
class Filter
  include ActiveAttr::Model
  attribute term
  # Overriding to_key, to_param, model_name, param_key etc doesn't help :(
end

class SpecialFilter < Filter
end
```

How do I override the ActiveModel to generate the **(same) predefined input names for all subclasses**?

```
= form_for SpecialFilter.new, url: 'xx' do |f|
  = f.text_field :term
```

So instead of `<input name='special_filter[term]' />` I need to get `<input name='filter[term]' />`

**NOTE:** The scenario is way much more complicated (with simple_form and radios/checkboxes/dropdowns etc), so please do not suggest to change the name of the class or similar workarounds. I really do need to have the **consistent name** to be used by the form builder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :

```
= form_for SpecialFilter.new, as: 'filter', url: 'xx' do |f|
  = f.text_field :term
```

Comment: Thanks. That does the job. I'm still curious how to do it on the model (what do we need to override from ActiveModel?)

Comment: I doubt this is happening at ActiveModel level. It seems to be at a form_helper level. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/beba8267c96a3dbc1f505ecc099dbf14db8dde4c/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb on how exactly the form is generated.

Comment: actually the default is on ActiveModel level, see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/beba8267c96a3dbc1f505ecc099dbf14db8dde4c/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L369

Answer (score 6):

As Divya Bhargov answered, if you take a look at the source code you'll find out the internal call stack should end up like below.

```
 # actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb
 ActiveModel::Naming.param_key(SpecialFilter.new)

 # activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb 
 SpecialFilter.model_name
```

So, if you really want to do it in your model level, you need to override the `model_name` to your class.

```
class SpecialFilter < Filter
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Filter")
  end
end
```

The parameter for this ActiveModel::Name initializer  is `klass, namespace = nil, name = nil`.

But `model_name` is also used somewhere else such as error_messages_for, so do use this with care.