# Changing respond_to url for an ActiveModel object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activemodel, ruby-on-rails-4

**Summary**:

How do I customize the path that `respond_to` generates for an ActiveModel object?

*Update*: I'm looking for a hook, method override, or configuration change to accomplish this, not a workaround. (A workaround is easy but not elegant.)

**Context & Example**:

Here is an example to illustrate. I have a model, `Contract`, which has a lot of fields:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  # cumbersome, too much for a UI form
end
```

To make the UI code easier to work with, I have a simpler class, `SimpleContract`:

```
class SimpleContract
  include ActiveModel::Model

  # ...

  def contract_attributes
    # convert SimpleContract attributes to Contract attributes
  end

  def save
    Contract.new(contract_attributes).save
  end
end
```

This works well, but I have a problem in my controller...

```
class ContractsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @contract = SimpleContract.new(contract_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Created Contract." if @contract.save
    respond_with(@contract)
  end

  # ...
end
```

The problem is that `respond_with` points to `simple_contract_url`, **but** I want it to point to `contract_url` instead. What is the best way to do that? (Please note that I'm using ActiveModel.)

(Note: I'm using Rails 4 Beta, but that isn't central to my problem. I think a good answer for Rails 3 will work as well.)

Sidebar: if this approach to wrapping a model in a lightweight ActiveModel class seem unwise to you, please let me know in the comments. Personally, I like it because it keeps my original model simple. The 'wrapper' model handles some UI particulars, which are intentionally simplified and give reasonable defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is an answer that works:

```
class SimpleContract
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, "Contract")
  end
end
```

I adapted this answer from [kinopyo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330756/109618) to [Change input name of model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313291).

Now, for the why. The call stack of `respond_to` is somewhat involved.

```
# Start with `respond_with` in `ActionController`. Here is part of it:

def respond_with(*resources, &block)
  # ...
  (options.delete(:responder) || self.class.responder).call(self, resources, options)
end

# That takes us to `call` in `ActionController:Responder`:

def self.call(*args)
  new(*args).respond
end

# Now, to `respond` (still in `ActionController:Responder`):

def respond
  method = "to_#{format}"
  respond_to?(method) ? send(method) : to_format
end

# Then to `to_html` (still in `ActionController:Responder`):

def to_html
  default_render
rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
  navigation_behavior(e)
end

# Then to `default_render`:

def default_render
  if @default_response
    @default_response.call(options)
  else
    controller.default_render(options)
  end
end
```

And that is as far as I've gotten for the time being. I have not actually found where the URL gets constructed. I know that it happens based on `model_name`, but I have not yet found the line of code where it happens.

Comment: This is where Rails builds the urls from active model instances: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L163

Comment: @th3mus1cman thanks. I haven't yet connected the call chain from what I wrote to what you linked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem, but could you do something like this?

```
class SimpleContract
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :contract

  # ...

  def contract_attributes
    # convert SimpleContract attributes to Contract attributes
  end

  def save
    self.contract = Contract.new(contract_attributes)
    contract.save
  end
end
```

-

```
class ContractsController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @simple_contract = SimpleContract.new(contract_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Created Contract." if @simple_contract.save
    respond_with(@simple_contract.contract)
  end

  # ...
end
```

I may be way off base. Hopefully that at least triggers an idea for you.

Comment: Funny! That's similar to what I tried first, but I was hoping for simpler/better. Note: `.save` returns true or false, so your `self.contract = Contract.new(contract_attributes).save` won't work as intended.

Comment: Interesting, and good point about the `.save` thing. Is the reason you're doing the whole `SimpleContract` thing because you don't need the user to tell you everything about a `Contract` when they create/update one, or are you splitting contract saving into multiple screens or something? Can you clarify the motivation?

Comment: Right, I don't need the user to tell me everything about a `Contract` from a particular UI form.

Comment: Any reason, for that form, not to have the same exact model, just a different controller? Any unused contract attributes could just be left alone.

Comment: This discussion is swaying a bit far from my particular question; please just accept that I have good reasons for doing so. I'm looking for a way to change how `respond_with` generates the URL.

Comment: Fair enough. My suggestion there would be to pass `respond_with` the actual `Contract` record that's tied to your `SimpleContract` instance.